# searching through multiple tables with a stored procedures

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables Vehicle and Vehicle return(it was spelled incorrectly in the code),I'm trying to create a stored procedure where I can enter the engine number and it would search through Vehicle and Vehicle return to see if it matches the engine number and the criteria that it is in either of the table but every time only thing that works is if the engine number isn't in either of the tables here is my code

```
create procedure outbound
(
  @eng varchar(25)
)
AS
BEGIN
   BEGIN TRAN
   DECLARE @eng_num VARCHAR(25)
   DECLARE @eng_num2 VARCHAR(25)


 /* SELECT @eng_num= Engine_num from Vehicle where  Engine_num=@eng and Status=1 
  SELECT @eng_num2= Engine_num from Vehicle_retuns where Engine_num=@eng

    IF(@eng=@eng_num)
    begin
        UPDATE Vehicle SET Description_of_Vehicle='Vehicle has ben sent to Manufactory',Status=0 where Engine_num=@eng_num
    end
    ELSE IF(@eng=@eng_num2)
    begin
        UPDATE Vehicle_retuns SET purpose='Vehicle has ben sent to Manufactory',Status=0 where Engine_num=@eng_num2
    end*/ the lines of code that is the error is occuring
    ELSE
    SELECT 'No such Engine number was found'

   IF(@@ERROR<>0)
   BEGIN
     SELECT 'An unexpected error has occur'
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION    
     RETURN -1
   END
   COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a free debugging service. Your post is basically "here is my code, why doesn't it work?". You might want to take a look at this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: But I stated that only the else work the two if statement above it doesn't works

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a terrible description. Do you tell the mechanic your car is broken, or your doctor that some part of your body doesn't feel good?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough sketch of what I think might be required here. There is no need to use an explicit transaction for a single update. Also, I would highly recommend you look at normalizing your messages instead of hard coding those long strings everywhere. Not sure you really mean to set the Description or purpose column depending on the value of status. I would rather see those be foreign keys to a lookup of values but maybe that doesn't work here. I would also recommend you not use column names like "status". Using reserved words is problematic for a number of reasons. Last but not least, you should use try/catch blocks instead of checking @@ERROR.

--EDIT--
Here is some new code that handles the fact that you really do need two updates. I missed this originally.

```
create procedure outbound
(
  @eng varchar(25)
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT Engine_num 
        from Vehicle 
        where  Engine_num = @eng

        UNION ALL

        SELECT Engine_num 
        from Vehicle_retuns 
        where Engine_num = @eng
    )
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

            UPDATE Vehicle 
                SET Description_of_Vehicle = 'Vehicle has ben sent to Manufactory'
                    , Status = 0 
                where Engine_num = @eng
                    AND Status = 1


            UPDATE Vehicle_retuns 
                SET purpose = 'Vehicle has ben sent to Manufactory'
                    , Status = 0 
                where Engine_num = @eng

            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT 'An unexpected error has occurred.'
            --I would prefer a message here including the error message and error number instead of just "It failed".
        END CATCH
    END    

    ELSE
        SELECT 'No such Engine number was found'
END
```

Comment: You missed the fact that there are two tables: `Vehicle` and `Vehicle_retuns`. Still, I think your solution could be adapted to work, but you need a second `UPDATE` statement that executes when the first has `@@ROWCOUNT = 0`.

Comment: Ahh missed that. Thanks @jmc. In that case you probably want to put back the transaction and do this as two update statements. Probably would have noticed if we had something to work with instead of fishing blind.